# Run ansible playbook from java

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to execute ansible playbook from java.Can you please help me with reference could not find any good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to run your command using ProcessBuilder:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class AnsibleServive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runCommand("ansible-playbook test.yml -i host.ini");
    }
    private static void runCommand(String command) {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", command);

        try {
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder errOutput = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            BufferedReader errReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

            while ((line = errReader.readLine()) != null) {
                errOutput.append(line + "\n");
            }

            int exitVal = process.waitFor();
            if (exitVal == 0) {
                System.out.println("Command Successfully executed.");
                System.out.println(output);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Error ocured during running command.");
                System.out.println(output);
                System.err.println(errOutput);

            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to execute command.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to try-with-resources those `Reader` instances, and I believe you'll want to wait until after the `waitFor` to grab the Stream contents, since the process is running async but those Readers are not consuming async, so you can miss output by running them too early

Comment: Is it possible to read yml files or ansible playbooks and host files from classpath i,e resources folder and execute using java